# I can't render an array of icons in reactjs using skycons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in reactjs and I was hoping if you could point me in the right direction as I am having an issue with rendering the skycons in reactjs.

[display skycons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MavMi.jpg)

In the screenshot above my goal is to display a weather icons using the canvas but it doesn't show up.

This is my js code below: 
daily_weather.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RenderIcons from './icons';
import getNameOfDays from './base';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class DailyWeather extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            timezone: '',
            dailyWeather: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() { // lat = 14.5995 long = 120.9842
        axios.get(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/9d63fb2636b6ed1060be85b7f068f493/-33.865143,151.209900`)
            .then((result) => {
                this.setState({ timezone: result.data.timezone });
                this.setState({ dailyWeather: result.data.daily });
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { dailyWeather } = this.state;

        if (!dailyWeather.data) {
            return <h2>Loading...</h2>
        }

        const data = dailyWeather.data.map((data, key) => {
            return (
                <div className="panel" key={`arr${key}`}>
                    <div className="data-block" >
                        <div className="weather-icon" >
                           <RenderIcons icon={data.icon}/>
                        </div >

                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="panel-block">
                {data}
            </div>
        );
    }
}; 

icon.js
import React from 'react';

var skycons = new Skycons({ "color": "orange" });
const RenderIcons = ({ icon }) => {
    if (!icon) {
        return (<h2>Loading...</h2>);
    }

    if(icon === 'wind') {
        skycons.set("wind", Skycons.WIND);
        skycons.play();
    } else if(icon === 'clear-day') {
        skycons.set("clear-day", Skycons.CLEAR_DAY);
        skycons.play();
    } else if(icon === 'partly-cloudy-day') {
        skycons.set("partly-cloudy-day", Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY);
        skycons.play();
    } else if(icon === 'partly-cloudy-night') {
        skycons.set("partly-cloudy-night", Skycons.PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT);
        skycons.play();
    } else {
        console.log('error!');
    } 

    return (<canvas id={`${icon}`} width="64" height="64"></canvas>);
};

export default RenderIcons;
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is I am passing each data.icons to RenderIcons and RenderIcons returns a canvas that displays and plays the skycons.

Thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass as reference to the canvas element into the skycons.set() method, and I don't think Skycons are going to adhere to the react way of doing things.

First, here's a simple example showing how to get Skycons working with React: https://codesandbox.io/s/94p3v5ovly

You're going to want to put the canvas in the render method, and use a ref. Then after the component has updated, pass the refs of the canvases to the RenderIcons function.  This is all untested I'm afraid.  But it should point you in the right direction.  See https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate.

```
import React from "react";
const Skycons = require("skycons")(window);

class App extands React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.iconRefs = [];
    } 

    render() {
      const { dailyWeather } = this.state;
      dailyWeather.data.map( (d,k) => {
        if (!(k in iconRefs) {
          iconRefs[k]= {};
        } 
      }); 

      const data = dailyWeather.data.map((data, key) => {
        return (
          <div className="panel" key={`arr${key}`}>
            <div className="data-block" >
              <div className="weather-icon" >
                 <canvas ref={iconRefs[key]} width="64" height="64"></canvas>
              </div >
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      });

      return (
         <div className="panel-block">
           {data}
         </div>
      );
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      dailyWeather.data.map((data, key) => {
        renderIcons(data, key);
       });
    }

    renderIcons = (icon, key) => {
      if (!icon) {
        return (<h2>Loading...</h2>);
      }

      if(icon === 'wind') {
        skycons.set(this.iconRefs[key], Skycons.WIND);
        skycons.play();

      ...
```

Comment: Thanks =) I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the right direction, I was able to render the skycons using the ref attribute. =)